# Plot bar graph in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am learning reactjs and I'm trying to plot bar graph. So I'm trying to plot population race graph which change over the time and looks like this.
[Population race bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dBpS.gif)

For plotting graph I am using [chart-race-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart-race-react). But it seems like I'm doing something wrong in my code.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BarChart from 'chart-race-react';

import './App.css';
const API_URL = 'https://example.json';

const randomColor = () => {
  return `rgb(${255 * Math.random()}, ${255 * Math.random()}, ${255})`;
}

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
     countries: []
   }
 }

componentDidMount() {

fetch(API_URL)
.then(v => v.json())
.then(array => {
  const dataForVisualisation = {};

  array.forEach(element => {
      const countryName = element['Country Name'];
      if (!dataForVisualisation[countryName]) {
         dataForVisualisation[countryName] = [];
      }
      dataForVisualisation[countryName].push(element.Value);
  });

  this.setState({countries: dataForVisualisation});
})

}

render() {

 return (
    <div style={{width: "500px"}}>

     <BarChart 
      start={true}
      data = {this.state.countries}
      len = {this.state.countries[Object.keys(this.state.countries)[0]].length}
      keys = {Object.keys(this.state.countries)}
      timeout={400}
      delay={100}
      colors = {Object.keys(this.state.countries).reduce((res, item) => ({ 
        ...res, 
        ...{ [item]: randomColor() } 
    }), {})}
      labels = {Object.keys(this.state.countries).reduce((res, item, idx) => {
        return{
        ...res, 
        ...{[item]: (
          <div style={{textAlign:"center",}}>
            <div>{item}</div>
          </div>
          )}
      }}, {})}
      timeline = {Array(20).fill(0).map((itm, idx) => idx + 1)}
      timelineStyle={{
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: "50px",
        color: "rgb(148, 148, 148)",
        marginBottom: "100px"
      }}
      textBoxStyle={{
        textAlign: "right",
        color: "rgb(133, 131, 131)",
        fontSize: "30px",
      }}
      barStyle={{
        height: "60px",
        marginTop: "10px",
        borderRadius: "10px",
      }}
      width={[15, 75, 10]}

      maxItems = {this.state.countries.length}

    />

  </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I'm encountering `TypeError: this.state.countries[Object.keys(...)[0]] is undefined` error because my data is undefined here. How should I change my code to make my output as shown in `gif`? Is there any other library for doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue on your code like in `len` property of the `BarChart` that gets the error **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**. After I used null checking with question mark, I am not getting any error but printing 1 to 20. I am not sure it helps you or not. May be after changing that, you will get it solved.

```
len={this.state.countries[Object.keys(this.state.countries)[0]].length}
```

replaced by

```
len={this.state.countries[Object.keys(this.state.countries)[0]]?.length}
```

Comment: Thanks @Khabir but this did not solve all my problem but a part of it definitely.

Comment: You are welcome, I tried a lot to show the graph but was unable. you provided an code link on other answer where it includes conditional statement like `this.state.countries.length > 0 ` but `this.state.countries` is not an array, it is an object. you must remove that condition. Please check this code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-kepler-ecq0d

Comment: Thanks for trying @Khabir.I have got this output at some point but again edited it to get expected output. If you get any idea how this graph can be plotted please ping here

Answer (score 0):

You should just wait until countries is filled before trying to render anything. You can for example render BarChart component only if countries array has at least one element :

```
[...]
{this.state.countries.length > 0 && <BarChart 
  start={true}
  data = {this.state.countries}
  len = {this.state.countries[Object.keys(this.state.countries)[0]].length}
  keys = {Object.keys(this.state.countries)}
  timeout={400}
  delay={100}
  colors = {Object.keys(this.state.countries).reduce((res, item) => ({ 
    ...res, 
    ...{ [item]: randomColor() } 
}), {})}
  labels = {Object.keys(this.state.countries).reduce((res, item, idx) => {
    return{
    ...res, 
    ...{[item]: (
      <div style={{textAlign:"center",}}>
        <div>{item}</div>
      </div>
      )}
  }}, {})}
  timeline = {Array(20).fill(0).map((itm, idx) => idx + 1)}
  timelineStyle={{
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: "50px",
    color: "rgb(148, 148, 148)",
    marginBottom: "100px"
  }}
  textBoxStyle={{
    textAlign: "right",
    color: "rgb(133, 131, 131)",
    fontSize: "30px",
  }}
  barStyle={{
    height: "60px",
    marginTop: "10px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
  }}
  width={[15, 75, 10]}

  maxItems = {this.state.countries.length}

/>}

{this.state.countries.length === 0 && <span>Loading...</span>}
[...]
```

Note the [conditional rendering syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#element-variables).

Comment: did this work and output was as given in gif ? @Florian

Comment: I'm getting a blank screen after `loading`

Comment: I let you test my suggestion and see if it suits your needs. I did not setup your use case.

Comment: You can setup a code sandbox, it would be simplier to help (https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: can you test it from your end if possible

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-allen-4jof8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark is the link for sandbox

Comment: Also I think my data is empty which means `this.state.countries` -> [] after the operation @Florian